# Oracle Eclipse IDE for Java Dev 2019-09 Windowbuilder crashes IDE

Tags: java, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windowbuilder

Does anyone know which version of Eclipse for Java dev i would need to roll back to in order for windowbuilder to work properly again?

Also using JDK 13.0.1

> I have installed windowbuilder by going to help > 2019-09 -
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09 > General purpose tools >
>   and checking off Swing Designer, Swing Designer Documentation, SWT
>   Designer, SWT Designer Core, SWT Designer Documentation, SWT Designer
>   SWT_AWT Support, SWT Designer XWT Support, WindowBuilder Core,
>   WindowBuilder Core Documentation, Windowbuilder Core UI, WindowBuilder
>   GroupLayout Support, WindowBuilder Java Core, and WindowBuilder XML
>   Core.

Once installed i open up a new application window through Swing Designer, Click design, add some JButtons, try to add a mouse pressed event handler, and the my whole IDE crashes. This happens every single time, and spits out a crash report.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to reinstall eclipse? Are both 32/64 bit versions?

Comment: Yeah uninstalling and reinstalling did nothing. it seems as though it is the JDK. Using the Luna version, with 8 JDK fixed the problem. something must be broken with the newest IDE/JDK. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems as though it is the JDK. Using the Luna version, with 8 JDK fixed the problem. something must be broken with the newest IDE/JDK.